# Can I use a bucket with Customer-managed encryption (CMEK) for deploying an App Engine Flex application via Terraform?

Tags: google-app-engine, terraform

When I try to deploy the code, I get an error. Here is the code I'm using."

```
resource "google_app_engine_application" "app_engine" {
  project     = local.project_id
  location_id = "europe-west"
}
resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  project  = local.project_id
  name     = "my-bucket...."
  location = "europe-west1"
  encryption {
    default_kms_key_name = "projects/......" 
  }
}
data "archive_file" "ae_code" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "./code"
  output_path = "./code.zip"
}
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "ae_object" {
  name       = "code.zip"
  bucket     = google_storage_bucket.bucket[0].name
  source     = "./code.zip"
  depends_on = [data.archive_file.ae_code, google_storage_bucket.bucket]
}
resource "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" "myapp" {
  version_id = "v1"
  project    = local.project_id
  service    = "test"
  runtime    = "php"

  network {
    name       = "cloud-sql-vpc-test"
    subnetwork = "subnet-europe"
  }
  liveness_check {
    path = "/"
  }
  readiness_check {
    path = "/"
  }
  deployment {
    zip {
      source_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/${google_storage_bucket.bucket[0].name}/${google_storage_bucket_object.ae_object.name}"
    }
  }
  manual_scaling {
    instances = 1
  }
  noop_on_destroy           = false
  service_account           = local.sa_email
  delete_service_on_destroy = true
  depends_on                = [google_storage_bucket.bucket, google_storage_bucket_object.object]
}
```

Error :

> Error: Error waiting to create FlexibleAppVersion: Error waiting for
> Creating FlexibleAppVersion: Error code 3, message: Checksums do not
> match: 0 and -714528238. │  │   with
> google_app_engine_flexible_app_version.myapp, │   on
> builtin_app_engine.tf line 68, in resource
> "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" "myapp": │   68: resource
> "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" "myapp" { │

I added the '`cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter`' role to the Cloud Build service account, the App Engine service account, and the custom one I'm using, but it didn't help.
Also, if using a bucket without custom encryption, it works.